# How to maintain Id's of log-entries in an agile project

Tags: c#, log4net, event-log

Ok so Ive run into a situation I would like to resolve with minimum impact on our development group.

We are using log4net as our logging framework in a largish c# system (~40 production assemblies).

Now our support end wants to be able to correlate logged events with a database they maintain separately. A reasonable request.

In production our main log repository is the Windows Event-Log.

---

At the developer side our current pattern is this:

Whenever you want to log from a component, you instantiate a logger like this at the top of the class:

```
private static readonly ILogger Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())
```

If you need stuff in the logging context, you put it in as-early-as-possible in the flow of every Thread, ie. at the receiving end of service calls etc.

Whenever you want to do logging, you simply do
Log.Warn(str, ex) - (or Info, Error etc)

---

Now we want to "fix" this log-entry to a unique "eventId", and we can supply an extension method to ILogger, that will allow us to do:
Log.Warn(int, str, ex), when "int" is a number with these properties:

- It is "mapped" to a durable store.
- It points to one and only one Log
  entry
- If the source code Log statement is removed, the Id is not
  reused for a new log statement.

---

My immediate solution would be to maintain a global enum, that would cover the set of possible "eventId"'s and just instruct the developers to "use them only once".

We would then proceed to do some sort of "intelligent" mapping between our Namespaces and "CategoryId" - f.ex eveything in the "BusinessLayer" namespace gets one categoryId assigned.

But I think there is something I'm missing....

Any thoughts would be appreciated on:

- How do you use EventId and CategoryId in your large systems? (Or "What" do you use them for)
- Does any of you have an example of a "dynamic" way of creating the EventId's, in such a way that you can maintain the simple approach to logging, that does not require the developer to supply a unique Id at code-statement level.

Sorry if my question is too broad, I am aware that Im fishing a bit here.

Comment: What does this have to do with agile projects? If the project is agile, then you shouldn't be exposing internals (individual logging points) to anyone, not even your own operations staff. Nobody should care if you refactor your code.

Comment: Well that is indeed a better formulation of the problem I have. 

I can't seem to bridge the gap between agile process and the requirement that individual log entries must be bound to event Ids.

Comment: That's because it's a bogus requirement. Simply have the log entries indicate which source line they're from, and you will no longer need static IDs which effectively translate to the source line. You may also want to rethink your reasons for logging, but I can't tell from your question whether you are also a victim of logging-itis.